# XML Spreadsheets won't wrap text

Tags: xml, xml-spreadsheet

I'm using XML Spreadsheets and cannot get the text to wrap

```
<Cell  ss:StyleID="bordercenter"><Data ss:Type="String"><divstyle="white-space: normal;"> value="Period &#10; <br/>Totals</div></Data></Cell>
```

When I added "white-space: normal;" it will generate the line break, but doesn't wrap the text until I enable editing and click on the column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the wrap Text attribute in the Style ID works

```
<Style ss:ID="bordercenter">
                <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1"/>
                <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center"  ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <Borders>
                   <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                   <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                   <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                   <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
              </Borders>
            </Style>
```

Adding the `ss:WrapText="1"` in the alignment made it work perfectly.